# start app with voice command

Tags: android, voice-recognition

I have an application that contains voice commands. I would like to access these
voice commands without pressing any button, only with a voice command .As in Chrome
("Ok google").

In Google developers in the section "adding voice capabilities", to "declare
app-providedvoice actions "explains how to define a label to start the app
but does not work me.

The app is for a mobile

Thank You

Comment: You need a service for that. Btw, what's the question?

Comment: how should we help you without any code example???

Comment: web-developers for android:


https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/voice.html


says if my manifest file put this:


<Application>

<Activity android: name = "StartRunActivity" android: label = "MyRunningApp">

<Intent-filter>

<Action android: name = "android.intent.action.MAIN" />

<Category android: name = "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

</ Intent-filter>

</ Activity>

</ Application>


I can start the StartRunActivity activity by saying "MyRunningApp" but this does not happen

Comment: actually it works but you have to say "OK Google, START my running app". With OK Google you trigger Google, with START you trigger the regular start of apps procedure and myRunningApp is the intent. It worked for me but it takes some some until it works. I don't know yet why.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the api of google

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/package-summary.html

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-speech-to-text-tutorial/

and you can convert the text returned into commands

Hope that will help you

Comment: But he'll have to touch the button to open it.

Comment: without you cant, because it's used for security reason, i developed i website based on voice too i tried to make it automatic but no way

Comment: Check out  [this application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bulletproof.voicerec). It has the ability to do so.

Comment: Thanks but I want it without having to press the button that appears, I want to use a voice command instead of a button

Comment: @JavierDonisMuoz the only solution it's to write your self vocal library

Comment: How do I can start doing that?

Comment: you need to find a way, noone can explain you how to do it, it's really hard